# How to deal with features that are only possible for some sample in Tree based algorithms?

Tags: missing-data, cart, data-imputation

If I have a data set where, for instance, I am predicting something about Bank customers.

Some customers have mortgages and some don't. For those with mortgages I want to include how long until their mortgage term finishes based on their 'original' contract. This could be either a positive integer (where the contract term is not finished) or negative (if they redraw etc.) or zero if they are at end of contract.

What to do with the customers without mortgages:

1. I don't want to deleting them because this will bias my data
2. Not sure how to impute them in this instance, aggregate values or zero seems like it will imply something untrue about the customer.

Things to note:

1. I must use a tree based algorithm
2. I have a dummy variable for "holding mortgage" so the model can split on whether they have a mortgage or not

Comment: Use a new dummy variable which indicates no mortgages or other.

Comment: Maybe not clear, but that was what I meant in things to note: 2. I've edited to make it clearer

Comment: I don't understand, where is the issue? You things to note 2 is unclear.

Comment: What is the purpose of your model?

Comment: @MichaelM the purpose is to predict activation of a new credit card

Comment: Then I don't see any issue with just running a tree-based method like XGBoost on that data structure.